# Any chance of an amd64+mac iso for current LTS, MacPro(orginal 1,1 2,1: 32bit EFI, HW 64bit)

Tags: uefi, system-installation, mac

Back in the "old days" ubuntu had an installer that would work with the first Intel MacPro's (amd64+mac, I think 12.10 was the last version).  Is there any chance someone could write a thunk to enable installing on these "hybrid" machines?

I came back to ubnutu first, but could not get a current distro to install, then I walked thru the other linux/UNIX/BSD(darwin) based distros with the same results, that being unable to boot the dvd/usb, The closest I came was PCBSD, it at least would get past the 1. 2. Select CD-ROM Boot type:  But would not actually install.

I am not looking to dual boot, just want a single OS.

Comment: BSD is not Darwin. they are very distinct, and in fact you would be relatively accurate saying that Darwin = Mac OS X. and there really is no one thing that is "UNIX" anymore.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/is-linux-a-unix/

Comment: strugee, your statements are incorrect, OS X was derived from a "fork" of Berkeley(BSD->NextStep-> OS X), at any rate I was just stating that I had tried the various distros, none of which were compatible with the MacPro 32 bit EFI. I wish I had the skill to come up with a fix myself, unfortunately I don't.  It would be nice, baring a thunk, if ubuntu would make those old +mac iso's available.  Still lots of these capable old machines out there.

Comment: ok, first of all, just because something was forked from something else doesn't mean they're the same. quite the opposite, in fact. are Cinnamon and GNOME the same thing? no, but Cinnamon was forked from GNOME 3. second of all, Darwin is not a fork. it's a set of modifications, sure, but Apple contributes back to FreeBSD and keeps the two relatively in sync.

Answer (score 0):

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/
you will find the ISO file you need to create a dvd and boot off of.  Don't forget to hold down the "C" key during boot up.

I have 14.04 LTS installed on my mac 2008 pro 2,1, working great!Runs like a champ!